# Whats the difference between RoundRobinPool and RoundRobinRouter

Tags: scala, akka

These are the two usages I have seen:

```
context.actorOf(Props(new IndexWorker(props)).withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(4)))

context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(4).props(Props[FileExplorer]))
```

Whats the difference between these two usages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RoundRobinRouter` is deprecated

```
@deprecated("Use RoundRobinPool or RoundRobinGroup", "2.3")
```

There is a section about router diffeerence in the [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/routing.html#A_Router_Actor):

> This type of router actor comes in two distinct flavors:
>
> **Pool** - The router creates routees as child actors and removes them from the router if they terminate.
>
> **Group** - The routee actors are created externally to the router and the router sends messages to the specified path using actor selection, without watching for termination.

Answer (score 1):

In akka there are two types of routers.
A pool creates its own routees. Group routers just "collect" routees so you can comunicate with them, but you need to start them your self.

Read [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/routing.html#A_Router_Actor) for more information.